# R Dataset Tree Ring - Analysis ideas

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am trying to fit an appropriate model to the "treering" data-set  (available in R). No simple ARIMA model seems to fit particularly well: for example, as remarked on p13 of http://people.stat.sfu.ca/~lockhart/richard/804/06_1/lectures/ModelOrderSelection/web.pdf , we could fit an ARMA(2,3) but a better aic is yielded by ARMA(9,9) which however seems like overfitting.

Any ideas how best to model a time-series like this, where ARIMA isn't working, seasonality appears to be absent, no obvious level-shifts or transformations, etc.?